# How to add BC-dates (age of a continent)

Tags: qgis-3, timeslider, values

I want to simulate continental drifts using the time tool of QGIS (V. 3.16.0). Turns out I can only insert certain dates into my attribute table. I can't even type in the date 0000-01-01 without getting a *NULL*-field. Typing in a negative value is just not possible.

I cannot get QGIS to read a BC or AD after my date, as suggested in a response to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139873/bc-dates-on-cartodb-com).

It would be okay for me to define the year of when the landmasses formed to the year 0000. But I cannot define years with more than 4 digits without simply repeating the date! (yyyy → 2020; yyyyyyyy → 20202020 instead of 00002020)

So what method would you suggest to define how many million years before Christ a feature began to exist in the current form?

Comment: Just use an integer. The datetime object is not designed with geologic time in mind.

Comment: Okay but how do I get the layer's and project's temporal options to read an integer field for the date? And how do I use the temporal controller to show the state of the year -2000000?

Comment: I doubt you can use date controllers built to Gregorian timestamps to work with geologic time. You should probably focus less on the "date"-ness and more from a generic value basis instead.

Comment: Thanks for your responds! I would be totally happy with any kind of numbers. But how can I visualise the changes if not with the temporal controller?

Comment: Geological time is measured BP, before present, not BC/AD

Comment: @nmtoken makes sense. Doesn't change the problem though, right? 

Answer (score 2):

Seems like temporal controler only works with standard dates. If you dont mind cheating a little you can create pseudo-standard-dates out of your real dates. So e.g. 1000000 real years become 10 years for QGIS temporal controler.

For this to do, you need to know a suiting divisor for your date, you can find out by looking at your max and min value. In my example I am using `100000` having a max-real-date of `-1000000` and a min-real-date of `-20000000`. So `1000000` real years become `10` years for QGIS temporal controler. Just use `make_date()` expression like this to create your pseudo date: `make_date(round(abs("integerfield")/100000),1,1)`.

Use it within temporal settings of your layer as expression:

[image]

Here a comparison between the two fields when using the above expression:

[image]

As animation it can look for example:

[image]

PS: no guarantee here that I did not mess up with zeros.

Comment: This is ingenious... I will try this! :D

Answer (score 1):

The [time manager plugin](https://anitagraser.com/projects/time-manager/) has an "Archaeological mode" (tiny button left of the setting button) that let you use negative date.

This plugin won't work with the latest QGIS release (the native temporal controler replace it since version 3.14, ) but you could use an older QGIS version or have a look at how the plugin handle negative date...

[image]

Comment: This seems to be a very elegant solution! Sadly my project is already saved in the latest version... I have to wait for the plugin to be upgraded.